# XCode why is it in red yet still buildable?

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded the VLC iOS app which uses libMobileVLCkit. I uses the build script included in the download which download MobileVLCKit source code and builds it, plus a few tweaking (XCode group and files pane points to the wrong folder). And I was able to build just fine.

I noticed that MobileVLCKit includes a few simple sample code, and when I run it it is fine. However, libMobileVLCKit.a which appear in the group and file pane on the left is red, even though it builds fine into the phone.

When I do remove libMobileVLCKit.a from the left pane, build fails.

Why is that the case? What does it really mean to be red?

EDIT:
screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458390/static-library-in-xcode-4) may be helpful. Maybe your static library isn't built for the current target?

Comment: But I could build just fine. I didn't use the custom script included to build the simulator version. But I did built it for the real device. Does that has to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I should think so. Generally, a red label means that the file in question is not present. The custom script must've been for building a fat binary (for both the simulator and device).

Comment: Red means its missing. As soon as you build it, it will turn to black.

Comment: @VatsalManot The script can be run twice, once with a `-s` switch to build for the simulator, once without `-s` to build for real device (I think still fat for different architectures). I didn't run with the -s switch, only run once without.

Comment: @jww  I build it, it runs in the device, but it's still red, hence I asked the question.

Comment: If it runs on the device then I don't think there's anything to worry about. Just ignore it.

Comment: [This](http://www.cupcakecoding.com/coding/fat-combine-script-for-static-libraries/) may also be helpful. Also, try building for release; sometimes that solves the issue.

Comment: Not much of an issue to worry, but I'm trying to figure out why. Because when I download only the MobileVLCKit (not the VLC iOS app source code which is the whole app), and I try to build an run the same sample source code included in the MobileVLCKit, it cannot link to libMobileVLC.a.